# Помогите пожалуйста определить типы выделенных предложений:

Tags: синтаксис

a) *По мере того как алкоголь волнами уходил, в душу заползала тревога: (1) **а вдруг ему было так нехорошо**, (2) **что он больше не вернется**.*

(1) - не пойму, оно относительное? относится к слову "*тревога*"? "*какая тревога заползала в душу*?" Или это отдельное самостоятельное предложение?

(2) - придаточное степени сo следственным нюансом?

b) *Она не понимала, каким образом это произошло, – **не из-за ее же обaяния, в самом деле, он рассказал ей всю правду**.*

простое предложение в составе сложного?

c) *... и вот так получилось, что он – **в чем не признался бы и себе самому** – влюбился в эту служанку.*

(знаю, как это по-английски (*parenthesis*), но ни идеи, как это по-русски)

d) *Он старался сократить дистанцию между ними, а она если и делала шаг, **то в противоположном направлении.***

это какое-то неполное простое предложение?
*..., а она если и делала шаг, то* [она делала его] *в противоположном направлении.*

Спасибо!

Comment: В 2b, кажется, должно быть "***обаяния***", а не "***обоняния***"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) По мере того как алкоголь волнами уходил, в душу заползала тревога: (1) а вдруг ему было так нехорошо, (2) что он больше не вернется.

Здесь 4 предикативных основы. Две первые основы составляют СПП с придаточным сопоставительным (союз ПО МЕРЕ ТОГО КАК – сопоставительно-временной). Две другие основы составляют СПП с придаточным степени и следствия. Между двумя СПП **бессоюзная изъяснительная связь** (тревога о чем).

2)  Она не понимала, каким образом это произошло, – не из-за ее же обоняния, в самом деле, он рассказал ей всю правду.

Между СПП с придаточным изъяснительным и третьей предикативной частью **следственно-причинные  отношения** (указана причина непонимания, высказано суждение, вызывающее сомнение).

3)  ... и вот так получилось, что он – в чем не признался бы и себе самому – влюбился в эту служанку.
Это **вставная конструкция** со значением дополнительного пояснения.

4)  … а она если и делала шаг, то (делала его) в противоположном направлении.
Эту конструкцию можно рассматривать как **однородные сказуемые**, связанные **двойным градационным союзом ЕСЛИ И…ТО с противительно-уступительным значением**.